# How to order items in alphabetical order in firebase cloud firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection called name in name it has some random names. I want to show name in alphabetical order.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, the documentation on ordering data is a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: yes I tried citiesRef.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.DESCENDING). But it doesn't work for me. Thanks for commenting my question

Comment: any other way to order name by ascending order

Comment: The documented way should work. If you're having trouble making it work for you, edit your question to [show what you tried and where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I highly recommend studying that link, as following the guidance in there maximizes the chances that someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confusing terminology by referring to document IDs as "names".

If your data looks like this:

```json
{
  "names": {                               // Collection
    "Tom": { age: 42, country: "US" },     // Document
    "sally": { age: 38, country: "AU" },   // Document
    "richard": { age: 36, country: "UK" }, // Document
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

`"tom"`, `"richard"` and `"sally"` are document IDs, not names. To sort these "names" using [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) order, the order understood by computers & Firestore on a binary level, you can use:

```kotlin
val db = Firebase.firestore

db.collection("names")
  .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId())
  .get()
  .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    Log.d(TAG, "Found ${documents.size()} documents")
    for (document in documents) {
      Log.d(TAG, "> ${documents.getReference().getPath()}")
    }
  }
  .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
  }
```

The above query would return `/names/Tom`, then `/names/richard` and then `/names/sally`.

This is because lexicographic order is not the same as alphabetical order.

```js
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  // lexicographic order
"AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"  // alphabetical order
```

As Firebase requires queries to pass through the index in a single pass, unless your document IDs all follow the same casing style, you will get a result different to what you expect. To overcome this, while allowing you to use any case for your document ID, you should store a new field in your document data that contains the lowercased ID of the document.

```json
{
  "names": {                                                    // Collection
    "Tom": { age: 42, country: "US", sortName: "tom" },         // Document
    "sally": { age: 38, country: "AU", sortName: "sally" },     // Document
    "richard": { age: 36, country: "UK", sortName: "richard" }, // Document
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Using the above data, with the following query will now return `/names/richard`, then `/names/sally`, and then `/names/Tom`:

```kotlin
val db = Firebase.firestore

db.collection("names")
  .orderBy("sortName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
  .get()
  .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    Log.d(TAG, "Found ${documents.size()} documents")
    for (document in documents) {
      Log.d(TAG, "> ${documents.getReference().getPath()}")
    }
  }
  .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
  }
```

Comment: thanks samthecodingman for taking time for me and posting this concept. My problem is in below link.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/16keq6h

Comment: I am waiting for your kotlin code explanation. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RSumanRadhakrishnan I have now updated the code samples to Kotlin. You should edit your other comments into your question.

Comment: Thanks man. It works for me. Thanks a lot